# Widget Switch only shows text and not the button

Tags: android, android-widget, android-switch

I have a switch widget that doesn't show up as a switch. Instead, I just see the text.

[image: Switch button only displays text and not the button]

Here's the code:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider5"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"/>
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try to change background of `Switch` control using `android:background`

Answer (score 0):

I faced to the same problem. You should set some drawable resources to thumb and track of the switch.
For example:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_below="@id/divider5"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON"
    android:track="@drawable/your_track"
    android:thumb="@drawable/your_thumb" />
```